# Good source for sound effect files on the internet.

Tags: android, android-widget

Is there a good source on the internet to buy and download sound effect files from the internet?

I will appreciate if you can name few places.

THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.istockphoto.com/audio is great for photos, multimedia and audio (istockaudio), it is credit based and everything is fairly priced... here are some other sites:

http://www.audiojungle.net/

http://www.audiomicro.com/

http://www.shockwave-sound.com/

http://www.audiosparx.com/

http://www.audionetwork.com/

http://www.royaltyfreemusic.com/

Answer (score 1):

Usually I find everything I need on http://www.freesound.org/